# Is there an alternative to SQLs MERGE INTO when need different parameters depending on INSERT or UPDATE?

Tags: sql, firebird

I am looking to optimise speed updating tens of thousands of records being imported from another system.  I am using Array DML and am sending the parameters in batches of 3000.

I am currently doing something like

```
MERGE INTO <TABLE>
USING ( SELECT 1 FROM RDB$DATABASE )  <-- This is purely to support the merge syntax
ON TABLE.KEY = :PARAM1
WHEN MATCHED AND TABLE.FIELD1<:PARAM2 THEN
UPDATE SET FIELD1=:PARAM2, FIELD2=:PARAM3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES (:PARAM1,:PARAM2,PARAM3,PARAM4)
```

The `SELECT 1 FROM RDB$DATABASE` is the Firebird v3 way of just selecting the number 1 as I don't use the result but the syntax requires a `USING` section but this feels a little hacky.

I thought about rewriting this as a script but didn't think it would improve the speed.

Comment: Is your current approach too slow?  What does "too slow" mean, specifically?  Separately, it appears from your MERGE that "key:param1, field1:param2, and field2:param3" unless the record is new, in which case "field1:param1, field2:param2, and so on."   Is that typo'd?

Comment: _"I am using Array DML and am sending the parameters in batches of 3000."_, Firebird 3 and earlier do not support batch execution, so what is actually done is the equivalent of executing 3000 times. In any case, try inserting the data into a staging table (eg a global temporary table), and use that staging table as the source for your merge statement. Or use an external table as the source.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for code to be less hacky and omit the pointless USING statement but after searching around the web this seems to be the fastest way to process bulk insert or update commands when you already have the values and they are not coming from a table.

I could put all of the values in a staging table and use that as a source which although produced a better looking statement, when testing, the speed was overall slower and required over 200 temporary staging tables.